# Ubuntu right click dropdown menu has very few options on upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I updated ubuntu 12.04 to **12.10** via software manager, and now when I right click on desktop I get the following dropdown menu:

[image: screenshot]

Is this the default right click menu?

EDIT: Now when i click on ***change desktop wallpaper*** it takes me to the settings page.
I guess the ***appearance*** package is missing.

Also the ***create new->empty document*** is missing.

One more: Arrange Icons is missing

Comment: The last entry, *Change Desktop Background*, is a bit misleading from what I remember. It has more than options than its name implies.

Comment: Edited the OP to update the problem

Answer (score 2):

Yes this looks correct in Ubuntu with Unity Desktop.

You got more options if you hover the mouse over the Panel on the upper side of the desktop

EDIT: I made a screenshot. It's in German but it should be the same.

[image: Otions Screenshot]

EDIT2: I made another Screenshot of the options i.e. create an new empty file.

[image: More Options Screenshot]

Comment: Well I do remember it also had a create new option and then new document, and some other options too.

Comment: You will find these options if you hover with the mouse over the upper panel.

Comment: upper panel as it the unity launcher panel? No effect either on hovering nor on right clicking on it.

Comment: You got one panel at the left side of the screen with the Unity Launcher. And you got another panel on the upper side of the screen. The same panel which integrates in the a window (i.e. Firefox) when they are maximized. If you hover over it you got the options File, Edit, View, ... Do this without any window is opened you will got the options for the Desktop.

Comment: When I right click on the desktop there is no effect whatsoever on that upper panel. Neither on hover nor on click

Comment: You wont get more options on right click. The options you are missing are not implemented in 12.10 on right click on the desktop. The options you are missing are now in the upper pannel when you hover over it. There is no way to put there options in another place while using ubuntu. Maybe xubuntu is more of what you want. -> I made another screen for you.

Comment: When I hover my mouse on the upper panel, nothing happens. Also the appearance package is missing from my installation