# Can change background only from Gnome, not from Unity

Tags: unity, 12.10, gnome, desktop-background

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 and I see when I right click on the desktop and click on change desktop background, all I get is the system settings dialogue and not the change desktop wallpaper dialogue.

How can I get it back?

UPDATE: (updated the title) I logged in using Gnome session and there when I click on change desktop background I am able to change the desktop background.

And when I do the same on Unity I am not able to do anything. It just takes me to the settings page.

Comment: It affects me too! I think you should file a bug report.

Comment: Did you also upgraded from software manager?

Comment: related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/259640/ubuntu-right-click-dropdown-menu-has-very-few-options-on-upgrade-to-12-10 by the same OP

Comment: @neo1691 yes I upgraded from the update manager.

Comment: @vasa1 I don't have those menus too.

Comment: I've also added gnome 3 launchpad ppa, and therefore my nautilus is upgraded to 3.6, maybe that's the cause.

Comment: @vasa1 that question makes more relevance when we talk about options in the dropdown menu on right click

Comment: @Soroosh129, you can ask your own question because of the mods you've done.